# Prevent undefined return type for useSWR with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, swr

I'm loading data using `useSWR` and specified the type as a custom interface called `MyInterface`. I also set `fallbackData` equal to a default object of type `MyInterface`. However, TypeScript is asserting that the return type of my `data` is `MyInterface | undefined`. How can I make it so that the useSWR does not return an `undefined` data type, but only a type of `MyInterface`?

```
const { data } = useSWR<MyInterface>(
    'myendpoint',
    fetcher,
    {
        fallbackData: {}
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useSWR` return type states that `data` may be `undefined`:

```
export interface SWRResponse<Data, Error> {
    data?: Data;
    error?: Error;
    revalidate: () => Promise<boolean>;
    mutate: (data?: Data | Promise<Data> | MutatorCallback<Data>, shouldRevalidate?: boolean) => Promise<Data | undefined>;
    isValidating: boolean;
}
```

Use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to ensure that your `data` is not `undefined`:

```
const { data } = useSWR<MyInterface>(
    'myendpoint',
    fetcher,
);

if(!data) return null; 

// type of data here is always MyInterface
```

Comment: I decided to go with this approach - thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use any hook with the data, things get more complicated

Answer (score 0):

You will always have the option that you won't get data back.
Just declare it as MyInterface | undefined and when you want to use it make sure your data is defined